# Can I use something to divide long expressions into several lines in the PowerShell command prompt?

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, powershell-ise

PowerShell ISE 4.0

In the `ps1` scripts it is possible to use backtick to divide a long expression into several lines. For example:

```
gps|sort -Descending -Property StartTime 2>$null|select `
-First 10 -Property id,StartTime,Name|ft -AutoSize
```

instead of

```
gps|sort -Descending -Property StartTime 2>$null|select -First 10 -Property id,StartTime,Name|ft -AutoSize
```

Can I do the same [*in the same position*] in the PowerShell ISE command prompt? I tried to use **`** symbol and the `Alt`+`Enter` combination, but it didn't work as I had expected [*At this case PowerShell interpreted `-First` as a next command*].

In the PowerShell ISE command prompt the next variant works fine (I had used `Alt`+`Enter` before the `select` alias):

```
gps|sort -Descending -Property StartTime 2>$null|
select -First 10 -Property id,StartTime,Name|ft -AutoSize
```

But I can't do the same before `-First` parameter instead of `select`. Does it mean that in the PowerShell ISE command prompt it is possible only after `|` operator?

Comment: What do you mean by *it didn't work as I had expected*? Did you try just Enter after `?

Comment: @PetSerAl, yes, I did. It means the copy & insert of that expression from `ps1` into command prompt will not work.

Answer (score 1):

It is a backtick, hyphen would be `-`, and yes just type a backtick hit `enter` and continue your command on the next line. Don't use `alt+enter` that will maximise the window instead.

If you use Powershell ISE then it works just the same except you have to use `shift+enter` to continue entering text. The backtick is needed if you are splitting a command's arguments, if you split just after a pipe symbol you can use `shift+enter` and just continue with the next pipe element on a new line.

`shift+enter` also works in Powershell.exe 5.0, so you can use it everywhere and not have to remember two ways to do things. Earlier versions of powershell I think you have to remember different key sequences for each.

Comment: It doesn't work. If I press `Enter` after `gps|sort -Descending -Property StartTime 2>$null|select \`` expression, then I get error message: `Incomplete lexeme of a line.`

Comment: Are you using powershell command line, powershell ISE, or something else?

Comment: I use `PowerShell ISE` host at this time.

Comment: Oh... You are right, it works fine in the `powershell.exe` (I checked it right now). I not expected that `powershell_ise.exe` can have other behaviour for this case.

Comment: Is it impossible for `PowerShell ISE`?

Comment: @AndreyBushman I updated my answer for Powershell ISE. You need to use `shift+enter` and if should all work for you.

Comment: but `shift+enter` doesn't work in the PowerShell ISE correctly if it was pressed before parameter instead of command name. I wrote about it in my theme.

Comment: At this case I get the error: `- First: The name "-First" isn't recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, the file of the scenario or the executed program`

Comment: So, `Alt` + `Enter` is *position-dependent* for the `PowerShell ISE`. Am I right?

Comment: Also, `Shift` + `Enter` doesn't work for `PowerShell.exe`. At this case it works like usual `Enter`.

Comment: Hmm, it may be version specific. Which version are you running? I've got Powershell 5.0 on windows 10 here and shift+enter works in both, but I think it may not have worked in powershell.exe in earlier versions. **edit** Just saw you added the version in your question.

Comment: WMF 5.0 was removed by Microsoft. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=50395

Comment: WMF 5.0 should be back around the end of February. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/2015/12/23/windows-management-framework-wmf-5-0-currently-removed-from-download-center/